# Google Shopping API Deprecated

Tags: google-shopping-api

I am having an working site which is using google shopping API but as it is showing deprecated and will be sunset till 16 sep. Is there any way so that I can use my current code with less modifications?

Thanks
J

Comment: The Semantics3 Product API (https://semantics3.com/) is a direct replacement. http://shoppingapishutdown.com Disclosure: I am one of the co-founders :)

Comment: Thanks Varun, Seems like great but couldn't found if there is any affiliate system associated with it?

Comment: @user2020721 you can associate your own affiliate IDs from your own programs to the URLs that the API returns since they are the actual product URLs and they are already canonicalized